# Как масштабировать размер окна(и всех элементов) при изменении масштаба в windows?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt-designer

Имеется монитор 27" с разрешением 4К. Для адекватной работы за ним используется масштаб интерфейса 200% (в настройках экрана windows). При этом окна qt под это масштабирование не попадают. Как это можно исправить? В идеале кодом + в qtDesigner (если таковая возможность там имеется)

ДОБАВЛЕНО:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
для понимания. 1 картинка - это как выглядит окно в редакторе и на предпросмотре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2 картинка - в редакторе и при запуске..
Как это лечить?
Делаю окна в Designer, но и код пишу тоже

Comment: Не удалось воспроизвести вашу проблему. Масштабирование корректно работает без каких-либо телодвижений.

Comment: на всякий случай почитайте еще тут https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev спасибо! добавил ответ на основе Вашего комментария. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию [@SergeyTatarincev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328752/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%b2-window/1329017#comment2349368_1328752), нашёлся ответ.

Собственно [он здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)

Резюмируя эту информацию, отмечу, что для мониторов с высоким dpi и неправильнsм скаллированием разрешения окон нужно воспользоваться:

```
qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR","1");
```

Лично я использовал эту команду первой в main и это решило мою проблему.