# Как подстраивать шрифт в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

Есть приложение на **PyQt5**, и при изменении параметра на 150% в настройках windows, все размеры и шрифты приложения падают, можно ли как-то исправить данную проблему? Например чтобы шрифты динамически подстраивались под данную настройку или что-то типо того.

Вот фото параметра в настройках windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит приложение при 100%:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот при 150%:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, зачем вам изменять параметры в настройках windows?

Comment: Я то не изменяю, а вот другие пользователи могут иметь в настройках 150%

Comment: может вы как-то предусмотрите, для таких пользователей, изменение размера шрифты в самом приложении.

Comment: не вполне ясно что и куда падает, тем не менее почитайте тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328752

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Я поправил вопрос, добавил как выглядит приложение при 100% и при 150%, дабы было понятнее

Comment: и в чем проблема?вроде все нормально